# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR After Installing SSL

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I am on a very newby level when it comes to AWS and SSL.

I got an SSL from GoDaddy. After that I generated the .csr file on AWS and I got an elastic IP. I created a subdomain on godaddy sub.mydomain.com that points to that IP.

I installed the certs following the instructions a found online, but now I get an error. I've tried installing apache2 on the EC2 and rebooting the instance but no luck yet.

Is there a way to remove the SSL cert or Fix the issue? When I got the SSL from GoDaddy, the zip had 2 files and ran the following command to install them:

```
sudo java -jar lib/ace.jar import_cert gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt gdroot-g2.crt sfroot-g2.crt 54581acbeba8a74e.crt
```

System said the certs were installed but now as I  get that error, on the EC2 we have a unifi controller and we want to get that SSLrunning to accept payments for the hotspot.

Comment: Please reformat your query. Its one giant blob of text. Reformatting increases readability.

Comment: Does it look better now?

Comment: Did you get a Wild card cert from GoDaddy to cover the subdomain as well? or just for the top level domain? Can you post the instructions you followed for installing the Certs as well?

Comment: I did not get the Wild card cert from GoDaddy, just got the top level domain.
To install the cert I followed these instructions
1. Copy the cert files to /usr/lib/unifi
2. Ran the following command sudo java -jar lib/ace.jar import_cert 54581acbeba8a74e.crt gdig2.crt gdroot-g2.crt
3. sudo service unifi restart

Comment: According to GoDaddy the cert that I was provided includes my subdomain

Comment: Can you provide the URL of this server so we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Sure, it's unifi.paradise-computers.com. at the momment I have removed the SSL, since we need the unifi controller to access our main network

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UniFi Controller issue with SSL from GoDaddy on EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358949/unifi-controller-issue-with-ssl-from-godaddy-on-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues my controller is hosted on an EC2 instance.

Check your system.properties which sits in /var/lib/unifi/ open the file with vim or your text editor of choice.

Have a look at your HTTPS options, the important ones are the ciphers and protocols.

The Protocols you need are TLSv1 and potentially SSLv2Hello there should be no other SSL protocols in there.

The Ciphers you ideally want are TLS, so for example TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

If you are having issues throw them all in, CAUTION! only use this in a demo /test environment.

```
unifi.https.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

Remember once you have edited the system.properties you need to restart the controller.

```
sudo service unifi restart
```

Lots of help on the Unifi page

[UniFi - SSL Certificate Error](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/212500127-UniFi-SSL-certificate-error-upon-opening-controller-page)

[UniFi - Explaining the config.properties File](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205146040-OD-UniFi-What-is-the-config-properties-file-)

[UniFi - system.properties File Explanation](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205202580-UniFi-system-properties-File-Explanation)