# UniFi Controller issue with SSL from GoDaddy on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

Scenario

I have AWS setup for a unifi controller, I've been to access it with https://myserverip:8443, I bypass "This connection is note sucured" and use the controller normally

Now, I need to install and SSL certificate to get the hotspot payment system going.

I have a FQDN with GoDaddy so I created a subdomain `unifi.mydomain.com`, that points to the elastic IP, I log on with https://unifi.mydomain.com:8443

I bought the SSL certificate from GoDaddy, added the subdomain to that certificate.

I log on my AWS with SSH, generate my csr with the following command

```
cd /usr/lib/unifi
sudo java -jar lib/ace.jar new_cert unifi.mydomain.dom “My Company Name” City State CC*
```

Then I do

```
cd var/lib/unifi

more unifi_certificate.csr.pem
```

Once I get that I copy and paste it on GoDaddy, download the cert files, go back to AWS copy the files with **filezilla** to **/usr/lib/unifi**

Then I run the following command

```
sudo java -jar lib/ace.jar import_cert unifi_mydomain_com.crt bundlecert.crt
```

They import correctly, restart unifi service and reboot EC2

When I got to any of the above address I get the following

This site can’t provide a secure connection ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I've tried different browsers, incognito mode, vpn, etc, I believe it's just a matter of SSL or my server

Comment: It'd be much easier to debug if you include the real domain. Either way, you can try tools like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and `openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com` to give you more information on the configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system.properties which sits in /var/lib/unifi/ open the file with vim or your text editor of choice.

Have a look at your HTTPS options, the important ones are the ciphers and protocols.

The Protocols you need are TLSv1 and potentially SSLv2Hello there should be no other SSL protocols in there.

The Ciphers you ideally want are TLS, so for example TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

If you are having issues throw them all in, CAUTION! only use this in a demo /test environment.

```
unifi.https.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

Remember once you have edited the system.properties you need to restart the controller.

```
sudo service unifi restart
```

Lots of help on the Unifi page

[UniFi - SSL Certificate Error](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/212500127-UniFi-SSL-certificate-error-upon-opening-controller-page)

[UniFi - Explaining the config.properties File](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205146040-OD-UniFi-What-is-the-config-properties-file-)

[UniFi - system.properties File Explanation](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205202580-UniFi-system-properties-File-Explanation)